# Why when I start uvicorn in my FastAPI service does my configuration method run twice?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I have written a service using fastapi and uvicorn. I have a main in my service that starts uvicorn (see below).  In that main, the first thing I do is load configuration settings.  I have some INFO outputs that output the settings when I load the configuration.  I notice when I start my service, the configuration loading method seems to be running twice.

```
# INITIALIZE
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load the config once at bootstrap time. This outputs the string "Loading configuration settings..."
    config = CdfAuthConfig()
    print("Loaded Configuration")
    # Create FastAPI object
    app = FastAPI()
    # Start uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5050)
```

The output when I run the service looks like:

```
Loading configuration settings...
Loading configuration settings...
Loaded Configuration
```

Why is the "CdfAuthConfig()" class being instantiated twice?  It obviously has something to do with the "uvicorn.run" command.

Comment: Since the *"Loaded Configuration"* isn't printed twice, I don't think the configuration was loaded twice.

Comment: Need to see how you print `Loading configuration settings...`

Comment: The question needs more information to be answered properly, I think.

Comment: `Loading configuration settings...` and `Loaded congifuration` runs before `uvicorn.run()`  the problem is not on uvicorn.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the command line that you're using to run your `uvicorn`?

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar setup and this behavior made me curious, I did some tests and now I see probably why.

Your `if __name__ == "__main__":` is being reached only once, this is a fact.

How can you test this.
Add the following line before your if:

```
 print(__name__)
```

If you run your code as is, but adding the line I mentioned, it will print:

```
__main__  # in the first run
```

Then uvicorn will call your program again and will print something like:

```
__mp_main__  # after uvicorn starts your code again
```

And right after it will also print:

```
app  # since this is the argument you gave to uvicorn
```

If you want to avoid that, you should call uvicorn from the command line, like:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000  # assuming main.py is your file name
```

uvicorn will reload your code since you are calling it from inside the code. Maybe a work around would be to have the uvicorn call in a separate file, or as I said, just use the command line.
If you don't wanna write the command with the arguments all the time, you can write a small script (app_start.sh)

I hope this helps you understand a little bit better.

Answer (score 3):

I have found another solution. Split script into `app_definition` and `run` script:

The first file contains only the app definition (no executable script).

```py
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()
... # your app code goes here
```

To avoid double execution, you can run the app from another file.

```py
# app_run.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

This can be run from the command line: `python app_run.py` without the need to write uvicorn parameters.